# NodeJS - Stream a large ASCII file from S3 with Hex Charcaters (NUL)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to read (via streaming) a large file in a Lambda function.  My goal is to just read the first few lines and look for some information.  The input file in S3 seems to have hex characters (NUL) and the following code stops reading the line when it hits the NUL character and goes to the next line.  I would like to know how can I read the whole line and replace/remove the NUL character before I look for the information in the line.  Here is the code that does not work as expected:

```
                var readline = require('line-reader');
                var readStream = s3.getObject({Bucket: S3Bucket, Key: fileName}).createReadStream();
                readline.eachLine(readStream, {separator: '\n', encoding: 'utf8'}, function(line) {
                    console.log('Line ',line);
                });
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't have anything to do with AWS S3.  It only has to do with whatever line reading transform stream library you're using....

Comment: Correct, but I wanted to give full context :)

Comment: If you wanted to give full context, you'd tell us what line reading package you are using.  We can guess, but it's better if you just tell us.

Comment: I apologize, it is line-reader and it is in the code I provided.  BTW, I have also tried readline package and that also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Brad its hard to help as this is more an issue with your line-reader lib.

I can offer an alternate solution however that doesn't require the lib.

I would use GetObject as you are, but I would also specify a value for the range parameter, then work my way through the file in chunks and then stop reading chunks when I am satisfied.

If the chunk I read doesn't have a /n then read another chunk, keep going until I get a /n, then read from the start of my buffered data to /n, set the new starting position int based on the position of /n and then read a new chunk from that position if you want to read more data.

Check out the range parameter in the api:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property